# React-Router: URL is changed, component not re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm new in react/react-router. I'm using react-router v4.

Story:
My site looks like this:
[image: Main Page]

In other words:
On main page if you'll click on `Link to Calendar 1` you're going to see `Calendar 1` with `Link to Calendar 2`.

When you'll click on `Link to Calendar 2` you should see `Calendar 2` and here's the problem...

The `url` is changed (is same like you would click it from main page) however the component (`Calendar 1` --> `Calendar 2`) is not re-rendered ...

Main App:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

App contains Nav + Main:

Main.js

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/calendar/:month?" component={MainCalendar}/>
</Switch>
```

And of course I use `Link` component:

```
<Link to={/calendar/3}> Calendar</Link>
```

Comment: What does `<MainCalendar />` look like?

Comment: Have you tried passing `MainCalendar` as a callback , `<Route path="/calendar/:month?" component={ (props) => < MainCalendar {...props}/>}`

Comment: @Aaqib it looks like it works... Could you please provide some explanation?

Comment: @Silwest its one of the ways you can pass props down into the Component by giving inline callback function as every time user will come to this route that callback function will be executed with the new set of props which will passed to the component ,  spread operator is used in order to pass additional set of props that you want to pass down.